MySQL Error 1452 but parent table exists and data types are the same
Here's the total error:

pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ncbi`.`chromosomes`, CONSTRAINT `chromosomes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`accession_id`) REFERENCES `species` (`accession_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)')

I am running a class that writes data into my sql tables one-by-one. When I get this error, the species parent table value is saved-- so the parent row does exist. Why isn't my child table entry working when they are the same data type and the same value?
I uploaded the whole thing for completeness, but the parent entry happens in def gen_gff() and the chromosome child entry is the first section of the parse_write() function (which calls gen_gff and the class properties to get the right values)
The error is only between the first two tables, Species and Chromosomes.
class parse_upload():
    def __init__(self):
        self.self = self
        self.data =  ['GCF_963506605.1', 'GCA_009733165.1'] #change everything to be the parent class property later
        self.csv_path = r"C:\Users\tyler\Downloads\squamata_metadata.csv"
        self.path_gen = self.gen_paths()
        self.gff_gen = self.gen_gff()
        self.accession = ''
        self.gp = ''
        self.np = ''
        self.chrom_id = ''
        self.gene_id = ''
        self.gene_ss = []
        self.exon_ss = []
        self.chrom_end = '' #for flanking 
        
    def gen_paths(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path)
        for i in self.data:
            d = {i: []}
            index_of_accession = np.where(df["accession"] == i)
            d[i].append(fr"{list(df.iloc[index_of_accession]['path_to_gff'])[0]}")
            d[i].append(fr"{list(df.iloc[index_of_accession]['path_to_fna'])[0]}")
            self.accession = i
            yield d[i]
            
    def gen_gff(self):
        gg = adams_gff_gen()
        x = self.path_gen
        for i in x: 
            self.gp = i[0]
            self.np = i[1]
            with conn.cursor() as cursor: 
                sql = f"INSERT INTO Species (accession_id) VALUES (%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession))
            
            return gg.lines(self.gp) #havent added doing the fna yet
        
    def flanking(self):
       for i in self.gene_ss:
           start = (int(self.gene_ss[i][0])-50) #plus 51???
           end = (int(self.gene_ss[i][1])+50)
           if start < 1 or end > self.chrom_end:
               None
           else:
               j += 1
               flank_id = f'flank_{j}'
               with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                   sql = f"INSERT INTO Exons (accession_id, chrom_id, gene_id, flank_id, flank_seq_start, flank_seq_end) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                   cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, self.gene_id, flank_id, start, end,))
                   #conn.commit()
       
       return None
   
    def intergenic_seq(self): 
        self.gene_ss.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        j = 0 #we need to make sure this doesnt reset and give us non unique entries,, should be a running tally until the program closes
        if len(self.gene_ss) > 1: #if there is more than one gene, so at least one seq
            for i in self.gene_ss:
                start = (int(self.gene_ss[i][1])+1)
                stop = (int(self.gene_ss[i+1][0])-1) #is there a possibility of this ever being negative? -- no
                j += 1
                igs_id = f'igs_{j}'
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = f"INSERT INTO Intergenic_seq (accession_id, chrom_id, gene_id, igs_id, igs_seq_start, igs_seq_end) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, self.gene_id, igs_id, start, stop,))
                    #conn.commit()
        else:
            None #dont make an entry
  
    def introns(self):
        self.exon_ss.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        j = 0 #we need to make sure this doesnt reset and give us non unique entries,, should be a running tally until the program closes
        if len(self.exon_ss) > 1: #if there is more than one exon, so at least one intron
            for i in self.exon_ss:
                start = (int(self.exon_ss[i][1])+1)
                stop = (int(self.exon_ss[i+1][0])-1) #is there a possibility of this ever being negative? -- no
                j += 1
                int_id = f'int_{j}'
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = f"INSERT INTO Exons (accession_id, chrom_id, gene_id, intron_id, intron_seq_start, intron_seq_end) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, self.gene_id, int_id, start, stop,))
                    #conn.commit()
        else:
            None
            

    def get_seq():
        return None
    
    def get_windows():
    #if we cant do them in sql
        return None
        
       
    def parse_write(self):
        seq = ['abcdefg'] #i have a feeling the fasta function will take a while and i dont want to run it until everything else is ready
        for line in self.gff_gen: #for each line in the gff generator
            if line['feature'] == 'region':
                if line['ID'] != self.chrom_id: #if we hit a new chromosome, reset and restart everything
                    self.intergenic_seq()
                    self.introns()
                    self.chrom_id = line['ID']
                    self.gene_ss = []
                    self.exon_ss = []
                    self.chrom_end = line['end']
                    
                    #run get fasta and save text output to a variable to put below
                    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                        sql = f"INSERT INTO Chromosomes (accession_id, chrom_id, chrom_name, chrom_seq_start, chrom_seq_end, chrom_seq) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                        cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, line['ID'], line['chromosome'], line['start'], line['end'], seq,))
                        #conn.commit()
            
                else:
                    #run get fasta and save text output to a variable to put below
                    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                        sql = f"INSERT INTO Chromosomes (accession_id, chrom_id, chrom_name, chrom_seq_start, chrom_seq_end, chrom_seq) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                        cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, line['chromosome'], line['start'], line['end'], seq,))
                        #conn.commit()
                    
            if line['feature'] =='gene':
                if line['ID'] != self.gene_id:#when we hit a new gene, reset the property so we can use it for subsequent exons
                    self.gene_id = line['ID']
                    
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = f"INSERT INTO Genes (accession_id, chrom_id, gene_id, gene_seq_start, gene_seq_end) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, self.gene_id, line['start'], line['end'],))
                    #conn.commit()
                self.flanking()
                self.gene_ss.append([line['start'], line['end']]) #use this running list to calculate introns and intergenic seqs once the chromosome is over
                
            if line['feature'] == 'exon':
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = f"INSERT INTO Exons (accession_id, chrom_id, gene_id, exon_id, exon_seq_start, exon_seq_end) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession, self.chrom_id, self.gene_id, line['ID'], line['start'], line['end'],))
                    #conn.commit()
                self.exon_ss.append([line['start'], line['stop']]) 

       
         
t1 = parse_upload()
with conn:
    t1.parse_write()
conn.commit()
conn.close()




You've not posted any sample data, nor the code that calls these methods. Sequence is important. If you try to insert a chromosome before you inster the species the constraint will fail. We can't see from the code you're posted whether that's the case.

This isn't a problem with the table definitions. It means you're trying to insert a row into chromosomes with an accession_id that doesn't exist in species.

You're missing a comma in cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession)) It should be cursor.execute(sql, (self.accession,)) so that the second argument is a tuple.

After you call self.gen_gff() you clear self.accession. But parse_write() tries to use this when inserting into chromosomes.

it makes no sense to use that. It's only meaningful when looping over the generator returned by gen_paths.

BTW, it's very strange to store a generator in an instance variable. The variable becomes unusable after the first time you iterate over it, so there's no good reason to save it permanently.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular The code does show the order and how it is called. My data is a 300GB gff file but I'm parsing strings from it, one of which are the items in the 'data' property. The parent table is called and made and saved to sql before the chromosome function is called

@Barmar Thank you for the advice, ill work on replacing the generator later. I also added the comma to make the species addition a tuple. For the rest, are you saying that the class property self.accession isn't saved at the first iteration? That the chromosome function is inserting either the second iteration value or nothing at all? Where did it get lost? I apologize if this seems simple, i'm quite new.

I just noticed that parse_write() has a loop over self.gff_gen, I didn't see that earlier. But that doesn't reassign self.accession, it's still empty from the self.accession = '' assignment.

I think you need to refactor this so that the accession is passed back as a result of these loops, not assigned to an instance variable. Then you can get the appropriate value in the loop in parse_write().
